# Bootstrap tab panel title and content equal height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[link I have tried](https://codepen.io/saravana_91/pen/oQajZw)

I am using bootstrap "**tab panel**" for my website.

I want to set **equal height for my tab title and description when I load the  page** as per the below image.

I am playing around setting **auto height** based on content for both title and description.

Anyone help to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style class="cp-pen-styles"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active equalHeight" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" style="height: 74px;">Home</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active equalHeight" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list" style="height: 48px;">
                    1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">
                    2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">
                    3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.5/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function equalHeight(group) {
            tallest = 0;
            group.each(function() {
                thisHeight = $(this).height();
                if (thisHeight > tallest) {
                    tallest = thisHeight;
                }
            });
            group.height(tallest);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            equalHeight($(".equalHeight"));
        });
        //# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: I want like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution using jQuery, since you are already using that:

https://jsfiddle.net/p4uztjbe/2/

Just remove the  `equalHeight` function and invocation and add this snippet inside `$(document).ready`

```
$('a[role="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var targetHref = $(e.target).attr("href");
  var $activatedTabContent = $(targetHref);
  var targetHeight = $activatedTabContent.height();
  $('a[role="tab"]').outerHeight('auto');
  $(this).height(targetHeight);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any possible to set the height when page load before click?

Comment: do you have  any idea?

Comment: The first tab is always active on initial page load, right? So just get the first tab's panel height on load like in the edit.

Comment: first tab loaded but height not setting automatically

Comment: Ah okay, I see. You set an inline style in your markup on the first tab and first tab content panel. You just need to remove the height that is set in the markup. The fiddle has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: Now okay. I updated my css from `visiblitiy:hidden` to `display:none` for tab panel inactive. I have to maintain `equalHeight` class?

Comment: No, look in your HTML and remove these two string `style="height: 74px;"` and `style="height: 48px;"`. Because we are setting the height dynamically you do not need to set it explicitly on the element with an inline style.

Comment: Are you still not able to get it to work? Did you check the fiddle?